# Changing popup menu's content programmatically

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, popupmenu

I'm new to Android Studio.
I've created a layout for popup menu and showing it after button click. In menu's items there's "add item" to add other items into popup menu, but when I simply do `popup.menu.add("Title")` when "add item" clicked, it just changes current menu appearance, not menu's layout itself, so when I next time display it, it won't change.

My code:

```
private fun showPopup(v: View) {
    val popup = PopupMenu(myActivity, v)
    val inflater: MenuInflater = popup.menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.group_menu, popup.menu)

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener{ item: MenuItem? ->

        when (item!!.itemId) {
            R.id.add_item -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val dbHelper = DBHelper(myActivity)
                popup.menu.add("Title")
            }
        }

        true
    }

    popup.show()
}
```

XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:id="@+id/add_item"
android:title="+" /></menu>
```

So my question is, how can I add items to the popup menu after hitting "add item" to make them last there?

Comment: On every call to showPopup(), you create a brand new PopupMenu isntance that will probably never be shown again (you don't store the object anywhere, so you definitely don't reuse it)

Comment: Ok, i did, but still, when I restart the app, menu's added content is gone. Should I save somehow the state of the menu?

Comment: Yes. Yes, you should